# Does Cloudant has conflic without outside replication into it?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm planing on having my database stored in [Cloudant](http://cloudant.com).

We do not plan to have replication into Cloudant, only outside for backup purposes.
Is it safe to assume that there should not be any conflict in documents from the inner-working of BigCouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to assume that the clustered "big-couch inspired" code we run at Cloudant does not normally create additional conflicts in your documents.  If you want to become a power user you can read up on 'quorum' in [docs.cloudant.com](http://docs.cloudant.com), but you can safely ignore that to first order.